# Error publishing source code from cloud build to a bucket using triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-source-repos

I´m trying to publish the html code from one cloud source repository to a public storage bucket in gcp through a cloud build trigger . However , I get the following error in the build each time I push to the master branch.

```
generic::invalid_argument: generic::invalid_argument: if 'build.service_account' is specified, the build must either (a) specify 'build.logs_bucket' (b) use the CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY logging option, or (c) use the NONE logging option
```

I am using the following cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", ".", "gs://somedomain.com"]
```

I think this is related with the service account associated with the cloud build .

The tutorial I´m following for this solution is here : https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/automated-publishing-cloud-build

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The error was solved adding the logs specification at the end of the cloudbuild.yaml and enabling the IAM API .
The bucket and the cloud build configuration where in the same project so I didn´t have the need to grant additional roles to the cloud build service account .

straight under the steps put:

```
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

Comment: Furthermore you can see the available options here https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#loggingmode

Comment: How do you do this if you only have a Dockerfile (no cloudbuild.yaml)?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Cloud Build is starting with a specific service account, and that account does not have permissions to store build logs in Logging.

Grant the Logging Admin (roles/logging.admin) role to the service account you specified in the YAML file.

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts) has more information about Configuring user-specified service accounts

Comment: I didn´t specified a service account on the YAML it seems to be the default cloud build service account

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Build [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs) covers all available logging options.

And the (meanwhile) correct role would be `roles/storage.admin`.

Comment: Furthermore you can see the available options here https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#loggingmode